# C# operators as functions

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, functional-programming

Is there a way to use operators as functions without declaring them manually?

```
Func<bool, bool> not = x => !x;
```

Similar to `(+)`/`(-)` in Haskell. Would be handy in various LINQ scenarios involving conditional query construction. Maybe some C# (4.0+) trick I don't know about.

**Edit:** here is a sample to clarify what I mean:

```
 int MyWhere(Func<bool, bool, bool> cond) {}
```

a usual call would be:

```
MyWhere((x,y) => x && y)
```

a cool call would be (assuming Haskell style):

```
MyWhere((&&))
```

Comment: What does (+)/(-) do in Haskell? I know C#, but I am not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: + and - are infix operators but can easily be converted into regular functions with () syntax, so instead of 2 + 3 you can write (+) 2 3.

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Could you elaborate on this? Preferably with an example?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? In principle you could get the operator method `op_Addition` etc with reflection, but choosing the correct overload is non trivial.

Comment: You _can_ call the operator functions in invocation-style. In IL. I think writing IL code would be good exercise for a while. `call class Program/X class Program/X::op_Addition(class Program/X, class Program/X)` ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

You can find the definitions (F12 in VS) for the operators you can overload, and there exists a

```
 // struct Double
 public static bool operator ==(double left, double right);
```

But there is no way to call `Double.operator==(a, b)`.

The Framework does offer a  `a.Equals(b)` for this particualr case, but there is no `a.Add(b)`.

Answer (score 7):

For documentary purposes: user-defined operator are functions, however the C# language explicitly prohibits explicit calls (don't know the rationale). E.g.:

```
public class X
{
    public static X operator+(X a, X b)
    {
        return new X();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var q = new X() + new X();
        X.op_Addition(q,q); // error CS0571: 
        //   `Program.X.operator +(Program.X, Program.X)': cannot explicitly
        //   call operator or accessor
    }
}
```

If you were writing IL, you'd write this:

```
newobj instance void class X::'.ctor'()
newobj instance void class X::'.ctor'()
call class X class X::op_Addition(class X, class X)
stloc.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you are want to do right, you can use `System.Reflection` and `Delegate.CreateDelegate` to create a delegate to the operator method.

Of course i never testet it, but operator methods are **methods** so it should work.
This could also be automated ( To save time compared to the straight forward method ).

#### See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/53cz7sc6.aspx